# Where to insert threading into multiple-function scraper using current futures

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a scraper which uses Selenium to visit various websites and scrape meeting agendas. Each meeting agenda in turn has links to documents which I also download using requests. I am trying to use threading with concurrent futures to speed up this process. However, I am confused about where exactly in my code I need to use concurrent futures.

First I have a list of districts:

```
district_list = [
   {'url':'blabla.com', 'name':'A', 'state':'MD'},
    {'url':'yadayada.com', 'name':'B', 'state':'NC'},
    {'url':'etcetc.com', 'name':'C', 'state':'CA'}
]
```

Then I define various functions:

```
def parse_agenda(agenda_text, url, district_name, state):
   #Function here that goes through the agenda and returns a list of links
   return df, links, formatted_date

def make_directories (district_name, state, formatted_date):
    #Function here that creates a new directory labeled with the date of the meeting
    return date_directory       

def download_documents(date_directory, links):
   #Function here that uses the requests library to go through every link and download it to date_directory

def find_meetings(district_list, month="07", year="2023"):
#Function here to download documents for every meeting in a particular month    
    DRIVER_PATH = '/path/to/chromedriver'
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=DRIVER_PATH)
    
    districts_df = pd.DataFrame()

    start_time = time.time()
    
    for district in district_list:

        #Various steps to click through the website, check if there is a meeting, then grab the text of the agenda
        districts_df = pd.concat([districts_df, df])
        df, links, formatted_date = parse_agenda(agenda_text, url, district_name, state)
        date_directory = make_directories(district_name, state, formatted_date)
        download_documents(date_directory, links)
        
    driver.quit()

    return districts_df
```

Once I define all the functions above, I can do this for loop. It works, and returns a dataframe summarizing all the meetings that I was able to scrape, but it's very slow.

```
for district in district_list:
    districts_df = find_meetings(district_list)
```

I am not quite sure how to use concurrent futures to speed up this code. First, I tried this but it just results in multiple drivers opening and then all of them quitting within a few seconds:

```
threads = min(30, len(district_list))
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = threads) as executor:
    executor.map(find_meetings, district_list)
```

Then I tried replacing `download_documents(date_directory, links)` with the following, but it did not work because I could not figure out a way to include the date_directory argument:

```
threads = min(30, len(links))
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = threads) as executor:
    executor.map(download_documents, links)
```

Any ideas?